# MatLab C++ Shared Dll Library Initialization Crash

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, crash, matlab-compiler

I am using Matlab 2013a and Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to use MatLab compiled dll from a C++ console application. My simple Matlab test dll and console application is compiled for 64bit machines (I made sure they are 64bit via dumpbin). I also have correct version of MCR installed on my machine (even if it's not necessary).

I setup my compiler using "mbuild -setup" command.

I compile my .m file using this command line: "mcc -v -W cpplib:mylib -T link:lib myFunc" successfully.

In my console application, I include these libraries: mylib.lib, mclmcrrt.lib, mclmcr.lib, libmx.lib, libmat.lib and use the libraries in this path "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"

When I debug my program, it successfully initializes MCR using this call: "mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0)" but when I call "mylibInitialize()" in order to initialize my library, program crashes. It doesn't even throw an axception therefore I cannot handle it using try/catch block. It gives unhandled exception and access vialoation error message.

These are sample debug output messages I got;

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xercesc_2_7::NoSuchElementException at memory location 0x000000E263EF4E48.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x000000E263EF4E40.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xercesc_2_7::NoSuchElementException at memory location 0x000000E263EF4E48.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x000000E2643FF630.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x000000E2642FFCD0.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::AES_PHM_Decryption::InvalidCiphertextOrKey at memory location 0x000000E264EFB0F0.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x000000E264EF4C10.**

**First-chance exception at 0x00007FFA22761F08 in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: varflowFailedException at memory location 0x000000E264EF9410. The thread 0x3550 has exited with code 0 (0x0). 'MatlabTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hgbuiltins.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.**

**First-chance exception at 0x0000000000B46E60 (m_interpreter.dll) in MatlabTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000064EF3B90. Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000B46E60 (m_interpreter.dll) in MatlabTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000064EF3B90.**

**The program '[12952] MatlabTest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).**

I installed MCR to another machine and tried to run this console application. I got the same result.

I tried Loren's Vigenere example too,
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/#respond

It didn't work either.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems problem is MATLAB and Visual Studio version mismatch. If I use MatLab 2016a with Visual Studio 2013, there is no problem and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with Matlab2017 + VS 2015.
Probably there is some conflict with java used by MATLAB.

I've fixed it by using

```
const char *args[] = {"-nojvm"};
const int count = sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0]);
mclInitializeApplication(args, count))
```

instead of

```
mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0)
```

Comment: You will lose UI of Matlab (do you really need them when call it from C++?), but anyway it's better then access violation.